# api link not working, TCP connection httpparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tcp, httparty

So I'm trying to connect to the stubhub API:

However I keep getting this error

```
SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to api.stubhub.com:443 (Hostname not known: api.stubhub.com)
```

Any ideas what the issue with this is and how i would go about fixing it?

Here is my code for it:

```
 stubhubapi1 = `HTTParty.get(URI.encode('https://api.stubhub.com/search/catalog/events/v3/?parking=false&status=active&fieldList=id,name,description,eventUrl,eventDateLocal,ticketInfo,imageUrl&sort=popularity&desc&allowedViewingDomain=stubhub.co.uk&q=' + row.eventname + '&date=' + row.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' TO ' + date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + ''), headers: {"Authorization" => "Bearer API KEY HERE"}).parsed_response`
```

Comment: Do you run that command under a proxy?

Comment: Nope not at all, just a direct link